# In the derivative of the product of two functions , why (dx)² is ignored?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, products

I was digging deeply in the fundamentals of calculus, I found that in the famous '3Blue1Brown' channel, when demonstrating the process of finding the derivative of the product of two functions , (dx) ² is ignored because it becomes so tiny when dx is going closer and closer to zero.

I think that our calculus can be more precise if we don't ignore it, actually I think we shouldn't ignore it as this is math and not physics or such, the question is how our calculus is still valid and reliable if we give up even a tiny bit of precision.

The following image shows the details of the demonstration:

[image]

Comment: Because if you're going after that approach, then $dx$ is infinitesimal and the square of an infinitesimal *is* zero. Alternatively, write everything with $\Delta x$ instead; at some point, you'll end up with $(\Delta x)^2 / \Delta x$, which tends to zero as $\Delta x$ does.

Comment: We don't give up on the precision, it's just that it truly does vanish in the limit, as @T.Bongers explained. 3Blue1Brown is there just giving intuition, he's not explaining the actual formalization.

Comment: Clear , i would accept your answer if you add some reference to it ,  i don't want to delete this question , as someone else would find it useful , thanks ^^

Comment: The quadratic variation of x, y etc is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With all of the terms in $$df=\sin(x)d(x^2)+x^2d\sin(x)+d(x^2)d\sin(x)$$ to move forward, you will divide by $dx$: $$\frac{df}{dx}=\sin(x)\frac{d(x^2)}{dx}+x^2\frac{d\sin(x)}{dx}+d(x^2)\frac{d\sin(x)}{dx}$$ (I'm using $d$ as a positive quantity prior to taking the limit.)

Now take the limit as $dx\to0$ (which compels $d(x^2)\to0$).

$$\frac{df}{dx}=\sin(x)2x+x^2\cos(x)+0\cdot\cos(x)$$

So after taking the limit, this additional term certainly contributes $0$. (Note that I could have paired the last denominator with $d(x^2)$ instead, but then $d\sin(x)\to0$ and the end result is the same.)